# How can I change the data type of a field in a structure array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, type-conversion, vectorization, matlab-struct

I have a 2417-by-50 structure array in MATLAB and am trying to find a vectorized way to convert some of the field types:

1. I have a column of characters that I want to convert into a string type:

   ```
   [DataS.Sector] = string([DataS.Sector]);
   ```

   but its not working. I don't want to use a loop since it take so much time.
2. Same issue, but converting to numeric values. Right now I'm using a loop that takes a really long time:

   ```
   for i = 1:length(DataS)
     for j = 1:numel(Vectorpour)
       DataS(i).(DataSfieldname{k}) = str2double(DataS(i).(DataSfieldname{k}))
     end
   end
   ```

How can I vectorize each of these approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform both of these conversions across all elements of your [structure array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) by capturing the field values in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), doing the conversion (using [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) or [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html)), converting the result to a cell array using [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), then overwriting the original fields using a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
% For part A:
temp = num2cell(string({DataS.Sector}));
[DataS.Sector] = temp{:};

% For part B:
temp = num2cell(str2double({DataS.(DataSfieldname{k})}));
[DataS.(DataSfieldname{k})] = temp{:};
```